# How to transform last two numbers to decimal (int to float) in php?

Tags: php

I need transform `100` to `1.00`, `345` to `3.45`  or any number with 3 digits or more to record in db like a decimal.

Don't need add `.00`, just transform last two numbers in decimal.

I try `number_format($num, 2)` but is wrong.

Comment: Well, why not `number_format($num/100, 2)`?

Comment: Please send it as an answer so I can give it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems, that you want to divide your numbers to `100`, so using `number_format()` with the appropriate `$decimal_separator` and `$thousands_separator` is an option:

```
<?php
echo number_format($num / 100, 2, '.', '');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! :) 
Waiting 7 minutes (stackoverflow rules)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are converting from an integer to a float, you can achieve this simply by dividing the number by 100.

```php
$input = 100;
$value = floatval($input) / 100;
$value = number_format($value, 2); 
echo $value;
```

You may then use number_format (as you were using before) to force two decimal places after any evenly divided float numbers (such as 100).

**Demo:** [PHP Sandbox Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9ac7155e9e6e49d8453db0c7806f1223fbc8d18b)